# How to display specific posts?? Actioncontroller Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

I'm trying to make Podcast pages. On the index page, I want to display **the latest podcast at the top**, **next three podcasts in the middle**, and **rest of all at the bottom of the page**

For example, I have 25 episodes and want to display like below

> 25  at the top
>
> 22, 23, 24 in the middle
>
> 21,20,19,18 ~ 1  at the bottom

My controller

```
class PodcastsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_podcast, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /podcasts
  # GET /podcasts.json

  def index
    @podcasts = Podcast.order("created_at DESC").limit(1)

  end



  # GET /podcasts/1
  # GET /podcasts/1.json
  def show
    @podcasts = Podcast.all
  end

  # GET /podcasts/new
  def new
    @podcast = Podcast.new
  end

  # GET /podcasts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /podcasts
  # POST /podcasts.json
  def create
    @podcast = Podcast.new(podcast_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @podcast.save
        format.html { redirect_to @podcast, notice: 'Podcast was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @podcast }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @podcast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /podcasts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /podcasts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @podcast.update(podcast_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @podcast, notice: 'Podcast was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @podcast }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @podcast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /podcasts/1
  # DELETE /podcasts/1.json
  def destroy
    @podcast.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to podcasts_url, notice: "#{@pocast.title} was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def find_podcast
      @podcast = Podcast.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def podcast_params
      params.require(:podcast).permit(:episode_url, :episode_title, :episode_description, :episode_audio_url, :episode_number)
    end
end
```

index.html.haml

```
%section.no-spacing
  .row   
    .columns.large-12
      - @podcasts.each do |podcast|
         %h3
           = podcast.episode_number
           = podcast.episode_audio_url
           = podcast.episode_description
```

So far, I could display the latest one but stuck at showing three(2nd, 3rd, 4th) and rest of the pages (5th ~ all) in descending order.

Appreciates your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this.
First of all, it would be great to make a clean controller and a query object to work with the podcast list logic.

```
class PodcastsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    podcast_query = PodcastQuery.new
    # this is one podcast object
    @most_recent_podcast = podcast_query.most_recent
    # these are arrays of podcasts
    @next_three_most_recent_podcasts = podcast_query.next_three_most_recent
    @remaining_podcasts = podcast_query.remaining
  end
end

# app/models/podcast_query.rb
class PodcastQuery
  def initialize
    @podcasts = Podcast.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def most_recent
    @podcasts[0] || (raise StandardError.new "you need at least one Podcast")
  end

  def next_three_most_recent
    @podcasts[1..3] || []
  end

  def remaining
    @podcasts[4..-1] || []
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment!.  First, I got an error in model.rb file  https://prnt.sc/szudcz.

Second, when I run using your codes, I'm getting NoMEthodERror. Am I wrongly using the method call in view file??   https://prnt.sc/szuec0

Comment: Yes, the raise method must be wrapped with `( )`, I will edit my reply. You have to take in mind that `@most_recent_podcast` is one object, not an array, so you can't use `.each` method with it. You have to separate your view in three parts, for the most recent you should use `@most_recent_podcast.episode_number` and `.episode_title`. You don't need a loop there. But with `@next_three_most_recent` and `@remaining` yes, there you must do `@next_three.each do |podcast|` and then call `podcast.episode_number` etc.

Comment: Good. Yes, that was it.   Do you know why I'm getting this error?  https://prnt.sc/szumvh

Comment: change it to `::PodcastQuery.new`

Comment: Thanks!! you saved my day. I could successfully apply all of them to my website and it's working seamlessly. I'm so happy. Thank you so much again.!

Comment: Hi there, one last question. Is there a way to pass the validation error "You need at least one Podcast"?

Comment: you can remove it, that `raise` instruction is because `most_recent` method will throw an error if you don't have any podcast, but it should not be a problem for you right now

Answer (score 0):

First, change your limit to 25.

```
def index
  @podcasts = Podcast
    .order("created_at DESC")
    .limit(25)
end
```

Then use [`Array#shift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-shift) to take the elements you need off the array.

```
latest = @podcasts.shift
next_three = @podcasts.shift(3)
the_rest = @podcasts
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!.   I tried to set up those three in both model and controller but didn't work. When I put the code into the model, then I get "undefined method error", and controller gets no result. 

If you don't mind, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @carrey They would either be in the view, or in the controller as `@latest = ...`.

Comment: Sorry, But I still get a NoMethodError in controller#index

https://prnt.sc/szsw3c

Screenshot is attached.

Comment: My mistake. @podcasts is not an Array, but an ActiveRecord::Relation. Simplest is to turn it into an Array with .to_a. This is fine for small queries, but avoid it for large ones. Sorry this is brief, I'm on a phone.

Comment: No problem. Is there a way to keep ActiveRecord:Relation and achieve my goal? or Should I change it to array?

Comment: @carrey Yes, I believe you can use .next I believe to get the next row. `@podcasts.next` for the first. I don't think there's a next(3) so `(1..3).map { @podcasts.next }` should do. Then `@podcasts.each` for the rest.

Comment: I'm having difficulty to do myself. Could you show me some sample codes??

Whenever I add a variable in the controller, I get NoMethodError. I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried in controller

`def index
    @podcasts = Podcast.order("created_at")
    @next_three = @podcasts.next
end`

in view file
`- @next_three.each do |podcast|
      = podcast.episode_number
      = podcast.episode_title`

Comment: @carrey .next gives you the next row. If you want three, you need to call it three times. `(1..3).map { @podcasts.next }` does that and returns the three as an Array. BTW there's no problem with turning this into an Array if it's always going to be just 25 elements.

Comment: No, 25 elements were as an example. Thanks for the help. I could figure out!